# How to destroy an singleton Object in Kotlin and force to call init block

Tags: java, kotlin, singleton

In Java, we can destroy the Singleton Object by below method.

```
public class MySingleton {
      private static MySingleton ourInstance = null;

  private MySingleton() {
  }

  public static MySingleton getInstance() {
      if(ourInstance == null)
          ourInstance = new MySingleton();
      return ourInstance;
  }

  private void destroy(){
      ourInstance = null;
  }
}
```

so the constructor will be called the next time.

In the same way how to destroy the Kotlin Singleton object.

```
object CacheManager{

  init {
     //some operations   
  }

  fun destroy(){
      //How to destroy?
  }

}
```

I need to destroy the Object and make the init block called again.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your "singleton" is not actually a singleton so you can't apply Kotlin's singleton support. Use a `var` and write all your custom code.

Comment: "Your "singleton" is not actually a singleton"  how it's not a singleton?

Comment: In the trivial sense that there will be more than one instance of it within the lifetime of an application. `val instance1 = getInstance(); onDestroy(); val instance2 = getInstance()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not possible in Kotlin; objects do not have the concept of being destroyed. If you need this possibility, you should not use an `object`, but instead use a regular `class` and implement the destroy logic manually, similarly to how you do this in Java.

Answer (score 11):

I just converted your JAVA code to Kotlin using android studio and the result is looks like a singleton class which allows to destroy singleton object.

```
class MySingleton private constructor() {

    fun destroy() {
        ourInstance = null
    }

    companion object {
        private var ourInstance: MySingleton? = null

        val instance: MySingleton
            get() {
                if (ourInstance == null)
                    ourInstance = MySingleton()
                return ourInstance!!
            }
    }

    var b: String="Default value"
}
```

You can test this by following code

```
 var singleton:MySingleton= MySingleton.instance
 singleton.b="Singleton Object Initlized"
 Log.d("Value",singleton.b)
 singleton.destroy()
 singleton= MySingleton.instance
 Log.d("Reset",singleton.b)
```

May be this approach is wrong. If this is wrong then i will delete the answer, please let me know.

Comment: Yole said the same thing you have posted. Thank you for posting in detail, it will help someone to understand deeply.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a destroy mechanism if you have to explicitly call the method. Similar to how you don't need to call an init block